# How is QT designer used to implement radio buttons for a QGIS field

Tags: qgis, qt-designer

I have a custom data form, created using QT Designer, for interacting with a particular layer on QGIS.

A simple line-edit widget on such a form (as with most other form widgets) requires that the widget has the exact same name as the field name in the GIS data. It is this which tells QGIS to populate the form field with the corresponding data.

How is the equivalent achieved for a set of radio buttons? Do they need to be in a group box with the corresponding data field name? Do the individual buttons need names matching the potential values? Or is it instead necessary to use Python to select the correct button and to respond to interaction with the buttons?